# Transport-level error whith simple Select query

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm trying to do something very simple :

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=x.x.x.x;Initial Catalog=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;")) {
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, NAME, LIB, L_TIME FROM  PROJECTS WHERE  NAME = 'Jon Doe' ORDER BY  ID desc", connection);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows) {
        while (reader.Read()) {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0));          
        }
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
    }

    reader.Close();
}
```

I get this exception :

> A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the
>   server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name
>   is no longer available.)

When I use Sql Management studio, it works, and I get 3258 rows.

OK, now it will get WEIRD !

- if I add '`top 3258`', I still have the same exception, but if put '`top 3257`', everything works
- if I remove any field in the query, everything works !
- if I change the where clause to "`NAME = 'Someone else'` ", it works !!

PS : I tried this code in LinqPad, and I have the same problem.

Comment: seems your connection string is not proper

Comment: I bet your network is flaking out while testing.

Comment: Is the Sql Managment Studio where it works running on the same computer as Sql Server is installed ? In other words, does Sql Managment Studio needs to go over your network like you have to do ?

Comment: No, it's a distant server, and I'm using Management Studio in my computer, how is possible that it's a network problem that occurs only with this query ?

Comment: When you run queries in MSSQL multiple times, do you always get the correct result? Or is it failing randomly like once out of 10 times?

Comment: It always works in SSMS